# how to do design in XML instead of Html in nativescript with Angular?

Tags: angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Is it possible to use XML instead of Html for design the screen in nativescript with angular app template?

Thank you for reading, looking forward to reading your responses!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **yes**: Angular is perfectly happy to accept XML for its templates in NativeScript -- we are doing that at my company Yollerhorn right now as we develop our mobile app, and we made the decision to help disambiguate our web templates from our native templates. The one caveat is that we've run into some strange errors around commenting and unrecognized XML, but in general it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're adding your user interface to HTML files in a NativeScript with Angular project, you're not writing HTML.

NativeScript markup is XML. Technically HTML is XML, but NativeScript won't understand it and a web browser won't understand NativeScript XML.

Hopefully that makes sense and answers your question.

Best,

Comment: Yes @Nic Raboy . So we can design user interface using xml. But in that case user interface is not support the web browser means webapp. That's why in NativeScript with Angular project, technically HTML is XML. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes technically HTML is XML, but you cannot slap any random XML tags together and call it an application. Web browsers expect certain tags and NativeScript expects certain tags. The two are not compatible.

Comment: this isn't what the poster is asking -- he's asking if you can use .xml files for angular templates in nativescript